# How do you beat the Incursion training missions in Elite: Dangerous?

Tags: elite-dangerous

In the Elite: Dangerous there are two "Incursion" training missions that pitch you against tougher opponents in waves.

The last wave is an Anaconda with lots of turrets that just shred my shields.

How do you defeat the much more powerful ship?

Comment: While I haven't played that particular mission, I can say that I've had luck against anacondas by targeting their power plants with multicannons while using chaff to improve your survivability.  Using an Eagle, I was able to destroy these larger ships (as soon as the reactor reaches 0 health, the ship explodes, regardless of hull integrity)...though it would usually leave *my* ship limping along, almost completely destroyed.

Comment: @Liesmith in this mission you have an ASP with two beam lasers and 2 missile racks of 8.

Comment: That sounds pretty rough; every Anaconda I've seen has had multiple anti-missile turrets.  Very curious to see other people's strategy for beating it.

Comment: The First Waves are so easy, but The anaconda just kills me every Time. Very tough Mission. Can You aim for Subsystems when The shields are still online?

Comment: @Streuner you can aim for subsystems as soon as you've scanned the target, but you won't actually start damaging them until the shields are down.  I've done some testing and seen that beam lasers are also very good at taking down reactors.  It would also be beneficial to stay on one side of the Anaconda (top or bottom); basically, stay on whichever side has kinetic weapons (rather than thermal weapons), and keep using your own beam weapons against them.

Comment: Currently getting my behind handed to me by this guy, so an apt question for me. I'd really like to know how you can manage to tell which side of the Anaconda has the kinetic weapons, and then how one manages to stay on that side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the time of writing, Elite at 1.5, this mission is broken and un-winnable unless you get very lucky with a glitch where the Anaconda can't deploy its guns.

With the PC 1.0 release they designed and playtested these missions, but there have been game design changes since then:

1.1 nerfed small and medium weapon damage against large targets. This is significant because that's all your ship has.

1.2 nerfed missiles - made them useless against shields and reduced their damage against hulls. This is important because the Asp carries these useless medium missiles as its main weapon.

1.4 changed the way module damage affects ships. Until this you could kill the Anaconda's power plant for a quicker kill.

1.5 improved Anaconda's weapon loadout and made its armour better defend its modules.

All these game balance changes have been good for the game, as it wasn't good that a medium Asp could be an even match for an Anaconda that costs at least 20 times as much. However they've made the training mission impossible - currently nobody has the Xbox achievement for beating these missions.

Frontier are aware of the issue but as yet there's no details on any fix or change to these missions.

Comment: Thanks for following up on this. I managed to get the outer ring of the shields down before I bite it.

Comment: @Ellesedil I've managed to get the shields down, but the small lasers do almost nothing to its hull, and all the while it's shooting back at me with turrets. In addition the Asp has lightweight bulkheads and no hull reinforcement - once your meagre shields go you have about 8 seconds to get out of range or into a blind spot before your hull is gone.

Comment: @Ellesedil if you run away the Anaconda disappears and never comes back, but you can only complete the mission by killing it. Apparently if you get exactly 7km away (but not 7.01km when it disappears) then it will stow its hardpoints, and if you return it will take a minute to redeploy them. I've not been able to verify this as every time I try it disappears first.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to use the 'y' key to target specific subsystems. With Anacondas I've found that if you take out their drive, they stop to repair and at that point you can just get behind them and stay there where they can't actually hit you!

Good luck commander!